# Apache Camel - sending xml parameter to http endpoint doesnt work

Tags: xml, http, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Below is my route

```
    from("activemq:queue:request")
    .routeId("urlRoute")
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .to("http://mydomain:8080/my-bin/myProgram.pgm?xmlData=<head><user>username</user><pass>password</pass><data>Some data</data></head>")
    .process(new Processor() {
       public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {
         log.info("Response : "+MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(e.getIn()));
       }
     })
    .to("activemq:queue:response")
```

The above route works fine since the to endpoints is hardcoded with xml data in http endpoint.... If i replace the xml data with ${body}, it doest work like below.

```
.to("http://mydomain:8080/my-bin/myProgram.pgm?xmlData=${body}")
```

Am i doing it right?? or some data type has to be defined? please help me out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

change it to:

```
.recipientList(simple("http://mydomain:8080/my-bin/myProgram.pgm?xmlData=${body}))
```

Good solution:

change myProgram.pgm to accept XML data sent by POST

Comment: The 2nd one cant be done, as i cant change the code on that side. The 1st solution thanks it worked.